# Как выполнить по очереди одновременные запросы?

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, transaction

Всех приветствую.

Суть:
Есть функция, к которой может быть несколько одновременных запросов.
Принцип должен быть такой, пользователь попадает на страницу создается запись. Идеальный порядок должен быть такой

```
+------+------+
| user |parent|
+------+------+
|     2|     1|
+------+------+
|     3|     2|
+------+------+
|     4|     3|
+------+------+
|     5|     4|
+------+------+
|     6|     5|
+------+------+
|     7|     6|
```

Но из-за того что нет очереди и запросы отправляются одновременно у меня получается что-то вроде этого.

```
+------+------+
| user |parent|
+------+------+
|     2|     1|
+------+------+
|     3|     1|
+------+------+
|     4|     2|
+------+------+
|     5|     2|
+------+------+
|     6|     2|
```

Пробую в эту сторону и безрезультатно

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$activate->activate($us_id, $request->input('tarif'));
DB::commit();
```

Как сделать так, чтобы следующая транзакция не начиналась, пока не закончится предыдущая? С помощью чего реализовывается это правильно?

Заранее премного благодарен за Ваш развернутый ответ.

Comment: зачем нужен этот порядок?

Comment: @Ипатьев Я упростил условие задачи для понимания, в контексте у нее есть смысловая нагрузка. Если интересно, то нужно равномерное реферальное дерево, где у каждого родителя, определенное количество дочерних. Из-за описанного выше распределение неравномерно и у каждого парента разное количество чайлдов.

Comment: А вы на чём именно кодите? К примеру, у того же laravel есть полезная штука как `Queues & Jobs` - посмотрите как реализовано и сделайте аналогично

Comment: У вас косяк в вопросе. В примере "как должно быть" повторяется строка  4 - 3. И в примере не приведён случай, когда у родителя несколько детей

Comment: @ArchDemon ошибку исправил. Насчет нескольких детей это не важно. Важна сама суть вопроса, как сделать так, чтобы на момент транзакции, второй запрос ожидал очереди.

Comment: Это зависит от задачи. А логика задачи не ясна. реферальное дерево - это не "определенное количество дочерних"

Comment: Транзакция и так ожидает завершения предыдущей транзакции. На то они и транзакции

Comment: @ArchDemon я это прекрасно понимаю, однако вышеуказанный код, дает результат иной. Я попроповал sharedLock в определенном месте, стало работать лучше, однако все равно на тестах 40 запросов в секунду вылетают некоторые ошибки. Так же мне не понятно, как сделать чтобы транзакция не выдавала ошибку, а ожидала завершения транзакции. Потому что у меня сейчас в логах пишется ошибки. Например если я дал 40 запросов, записываются из них 15 к примеру, а в остальных в ответе висит ошибка.